# Attempt to convert a C++ program to Java. Memcpy help needed

Tags: java, c++

I'm converting a C++ program to Java, and have hit a hitch in that there is no memcpy in java.

I've taken my best crack at it, after doing some research, but I'm really hesitant and unsure if this is doing as the C++ program should, as I found the information I found so far to be a little confusing.

(Java code still has memcpy in but commented out for refernce)

The notes for both 
Image = Input Image 
Output = Output Image 
N = Width of Image 
M = Height of image.

In the C++ code, an element is an unsigned short int.

C++ Code

```
void medianfilter(element* image, element* result, int N, int M)
{
    //   Check arguments
    if (!image || N < 1 || M < 1)
        return;
    //   Allocate memory for signal extension
    element* extension = new element[(N + 2) * (M + 2)];
    //   Check memory allocation
    if (!extension)
        return;


    //   Create image extension
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(extension + (N + 2) * (i + 1) + 1, image + N * i, N * sizeof(element));
        extension[(N + 2) * (i + 1)] = image[N * i];
        extension[(N + 2) * (i + 2) - 1] = image[N * (i + 1) - 1];
    }
    //   Fill first line of image extension
    memcpy(extension, extension + N + 2, (N + 2) * sizeof(element));
    //   Fill last line of image extension
    memcpy(extension + (N + 2) * (M + 1), extension + (N + 2) * M, (N + 2) * sizeof(element));
    //   Call median filter implementation
    _medianfilter(extension, result ? result : image, N + 2, M + 2);
    //   Free memory
    delete[] extension;
}
```

Java code thus far.

```
public static void medianfilter(long[] image, long[] result, int N, int M)
{
    //   Check arguments
    if (N < 1 || M < 1)
        return;
    //   Allocate memory for signal extension
    long[] extension = new long[(N + 2) * (M + 2)];

    //   Create image extension
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        //memcpy(extension + (N + 2) * (i + 1) + 1, image + N * i, N * sizeof(element));
        for( int k = 0 ; k < N ; k++)
        {
            extension[(N+2 * (i+1)+1)+k] = image[(N*i)+k];
        }

        extension[(N + 2) * (i + 1)] = image[N * i];
        extension[(N + 2) * (i + 2) - 1] = image[N * (i + 1) - 1];
    }
    //   Fill first line of image extension
    //memcpy(extension, extension + N + 2, (N + 2) * sizeof(element));
    //   Fill last line of image extension
    //memcpy(extension + (N + 2) * (M + 1), extension + (N + 2) * M, (N + 2) * sizeof(element));
    //   Call median filter implementation
    //_medianfilter(extension, result ? result : image, N + 2, M + 2);
}
```

I highly suspect I've done it wrong, just wanted to get some assistance on this. (The rest of the program is easy, as it doesn't use memcpy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java actually does have something just like memcpy(). The Unsafe class has a copyMemory() method that is essentially identical to memcpy(). Of course, like memcpy(), it provides no protection from memory overlays, data destruction, etc. It is not clear if it is really a memcpy() or a memmove(). It can be used to copy from actual addresses to actual addresses or from references to references. Note that if references are used, you must provide an offset (or the JVM will die ASAP).

Unsafe.copyMemory() works (up to 2 GB per second on my old tired PC). Use at your own risk. Note that the Unsafe class does not exist for all JVM implementations.

You should also take a look at "Tricks with Direct Memory Access in Java" (http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/) and "Java Magic. Part 4: sun.misc.Unsafe" (memcpy function in C++ to Java equivalent) for some additional ideas. These guys are deeply versed in how to do low level (and risky) operations in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Java has a form of `memcpy`, invoked as [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28long%5b%5d,%20int%29).

```
memcpy(source, dest, size)
```

becomes

```
long[] dest = Arrays.copyOf(source, newSize);
```